How can we pass Thread Number in Json path expression in jmeter
$..id1
I want to fetch the value based on the thread number i.e. if Thread number is 2 then fetch the 2nd value and if it is 5 then fetch 5th value.
I tried this -->   $..id[${__threadNum}]
but it's not replacing the actual thread number.


__threadNum this variable value is stored accurately, right?. the question is you cannot destructure the JSON response

You can use JMeter Functions or Variables anywhere in your test script, including JSON Path Expression field of JSON Extractor.
One of reasons I can think of is that first match in the JSON Array has index of 0 and first virtual user has number of 1 so the expression can return nothing in some cases so it worth combining it with __intSum() function and subtract 1 from the current virtual user number:
${__intSum(${__threadNum},-1,)}




More information on JMeter Functions concept: Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction
